# Zurich, [date] UNT. What does UNT stand for?

Tags: abbreviation

[image]This is a bank document. The context is clear, and the main interest here is an **UNT** abbreviation. I suppose it is something to do with a Zurich geography, i.e. region, district or else.

Comment: As amadeusamadeus's answer suggests, it could be a Diktatzeichen. Have you checked whether the signature at the bottom the confirmation letter confirms this hypothesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only abbreviations commonly set behind the date is the *Diktatzeichen* (dictation code). It shows which employee has drafted and/or typed the letter.

Official letters often aren't written by the signee him-/herself, but drafted by a clerk and/or typed by a secretary. In that cases, both usually put a shorthand on it, e.g. their initials, where necessary separated by a hyphen.

In this case, the letter may have been issued by the employee *UNT*, or it stands for a whole department that sends standard letters.

References: [1](https://www.wirtschaftswissen.de/unternehmensgruendung-und-fuehrung/arbeitsorganisation/geschaeftskorrespondenz/zusatztipp-zur-aktuellen-din-5008-diktatzeichen/), [2](https://www.sekretaria.de/bueroorganisation/korrespondenz/din-5008/diktatzeichen/)

Comment: Reference 2 (DIN 5008) requires lowercase letters however.

Comment: @guidot Yes, but technically the German DIN standard (*how* it should be written) doesn't apply here because the letter is from Switzerland. The reference is more about the general concept of dictation codes than its (German) standardization.